# Ember.js inflectors - where do they go?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create an inflector rule that specifies that that the singular of *criteria* is *criterion*. In the javascript console, I can get it work like so:

```
inflector = new Ember.Inflector(Ember.Inflector.defaultRules);
inflector.singularize('criteria') // => "criterium"
inflector.irregular('criterion', 'criteria')
inflector.singularize('criteria') // => 'criterion'
```

Here's the line I used to attempt to create an inflector rule:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('criterion', 'criteria')

// using a regex
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular(/ion$/, 'ia')
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting errors in the js console:

```
Error: No model was found for 'reviewCriterium'
```

When using the inflector rule with a regex expression, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

In addition, after googling where to place Ember inflectors, I couldn't find an answer, not even from the `EmberJS` guides. I tried placing them before and after the `ApplicationAdapter` to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? Where should I place them? Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So immediately after I asked this question, I found out the answer to my problem:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.singular(/ia$/, 'ion')
```

This solves the problem. I placed this right after the `Ember.Application.create` statement. I don't know if that's the best place to put it, but it works.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! :)  If anyone else is looking for information on this, check out this page: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization